# Get method arguments' class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-runtime

I need to get method's argument's class at runtime.

There is a method

```
- (const char *)getArgumentTypeAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
```

in NSMethodSignature, but it only returns @ if it is object. I need to get class of this object, actually detect if this object is NSArray or not. What are the possibilities to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long back I tried this.So took some time to reply for searching the code. Anyways here is the info.

The return data of getArgumentTypeAtIndex and methodReturnType for NSMethodSignature class will be "A C string encoding the return type of the method in Objective-C type encoding." - As per docs.

So you need to check the retuned char data and find the appropriate type by the following table.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html

I guess checking that encodings table gives you the answer!

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Note that the specific classes are not encoded; only the fact that the argument is an object (indicated by `@`).

Comment: So is it possible to somehow get the specific (even if custom) class name?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
if ([object_you_wanna_check isKindOfClass:([NSArray class])])
```

Comment: I don't need to check object's class. I need to inspect object's method's arguments and classes. So basically get signature of the method: NSMethodSignature *sig = [self methodSignatureForSelector:selector]; and then get all arguments and detect their classes. How to achieve that?

Comment: Olga that information is not stored by the object runtime, it only stores the arguments size (so that it can be passed correctly by NSInvocation). What you are referring to would have to be determined by a static analyzer, not runtime code.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[MyMclass class]]) {
     //enter code here
}
```

or

```
if ([obj respondToSelector:@selector(myRequiredSelector)]) {
     //enter code here
}
```

or use advanced interface described in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html